# removing all javascript tags from a json/js feed before processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

i am trying to remove some unwanted comments from a js feed before processing

if i try this

```js
data = data.replace(/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi, ' ');
  console.log(data);
```

i get the error data.replace is not a function.. is this because its still in object format?

the reason I am doing this is that there is the in the feed

```js
test test <script>console.log("some script")</script> more text
```

and i need to strip this out before processing as with this in knockout can not load in this data

data is a set of data in json format.

```js
var data = [
{
 'id': '1',
 'firstName': 'fname1',
 'lastName': 'lname2'
 'text': 'Text'
},
{
 'id': '2',
 'firstName': 'fnam2',
 'lastName': 'lname2'
 'text': 'text text <script>console.log("some script")</script> text'
}]
```

Comment: Can you include what `data` is? "data is a set of data in json format" doesn't help D:

Answer (score 1):

That's right, you can't apply a `replace` to an object. It needs to be a  string, so you should iterate through all your elements and apply `replace` to relevant fields

```
data.map(function (element) {
    element.text = element.text
        .replace(/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi, ' ');
})
```

Comment: Why would I get the error

ReferenceError: data is not defined
data.map(function (element) {

Comment: Because you haven't defined `data` before calling this method

Answer (score 0):

To simply remove all tags you can use the DOM methods that JavaScript provides:

```js
var data = [
{
 'id': '1',
 'firstName': 'fname1',
 'lastName': 'lname2',
 'text': 'Text'
},
{
 'id': '2',
 'firstName': 'fnam2',
 'lastName': 'lname2',
 'text': 'text text <script>console.log("some script")</'+'script> text'
}];

var cleaned = data.map(function(item) {
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.innerHTML = item.text;
  // find all tags and strip them
  var tags = d.getElementsByTagName('*');
  [].forEach.call(tags, function(tag) {
    tag.parentNode.removeChild(tag);
  });
  // save cleaned text
  item.text = d.innerHTML;
  return item;
});

console.log(cleaned);
```